# App size getting increased

Tags: android, google-play-services, application-size

Recently i have used `Fused Location API` for location purpose.
Before applying google play service library `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0` the app size was `4.3MB`(4,499,239 bytes) but after using this api it increased to `5.8 MB`(6,085,932 bytes). Only one class has been added to the project. i.e `LocationService.java` where i am calling it from service class and here is the code.

**LocationService.java**

```
 public class LocationServiceRACE implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        public LocationServiceRACE(Context serviceContext) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(serviceContext)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        public GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient() {
             return this.mGoogleApiClient;
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        protected void startLocationUpdates() {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(60000); // Update location every 60 second
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }
```

I am not using no other api's other than Fused Location and nothing is added/changed in ProGuard after adding google play services.
How can i reduce the app size where i just need `fused location` api?.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here at setting up Google Play Services:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

It is broken down into modules so you can import only the API's you need. In your case you would need only

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
```

instead of

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
```

which is the entire package.

Additionally, if you are running Proguard at the end of your packaging (`minifyEnabled true` inside your `build.gradle`), it will strip out classes which your codebase isn't using, further minimizing the size of your final APK.

Comment: Thanks martin. I have taken care ProGuard dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

How about using only location dependency?

com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0