# App size increases once the app launches

Tags: android, caching

Once I launch the app, "Data" and "Cache" increases[image].

How do I reduce these?
I have used certain libraries also. Do these impact "Cache"?

Comment: it is because of sqlite db data .. apk size doesnt include sqlite data

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha depends on the type of your app any additional detail would be helpful for a specific answer like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909451/app-size-getting-increased

Comment: @priyankamorisetti I haven't used SQLite DB for my application

Comment: app data is the extracted data/library/class file data which application apk patch contains. And cache data is the local data like sqlite and images cache data and your shared preference data too.

Comment: @AnkushBist I have used Shared Preference for my application. Is there any way by which I can reduce these cache data?

Comment: shared preferences will create a file which is likely to be about in kb's but the cache data is increased on you app usage like image cache and etc. Below answer is correct.

Comment: @Aparajita Sinha post you app gradle

Comment: @AparajitaSinha you can reduce the app data size by removing the unused libraries in your project. As after app installation all the libraries data is extracted to your device storage. And this will also reduce your apk file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is normal and expected.** Your app will have some data to store like if you have Shared Preferences, SQLite databases, etc. Once you start the app, the required data are stored.

Secondly, **the cache will also increase** if you are using the `getCacheDir()` to cache some files so that they can be retrieved faster. Like you have a list of images shown in the app using a RecyclerView and any image loading library like Glide, it is always recommended to cache the thumbnails so that they are loaded faster in subsequent launches.

Don't get confused that this is the APK size of your app. APK size and the data that is being held by the apps are completely different. Like your APK size may just be 1 MB, but you may be doing some heavy processing of data and your data size after 1GB. **It is perfectly normal.**